# Wordpress 4.5+ Multisite Domain Mapping

Tags: multisite, domain-mapping

I mapped a domain to my main domain and in the multisite network site administration, added the root of this new domain as the sites URL. When using the URL, I get directed to the main site (1) instead of the one I mapped (2).

Here is some information on my mappings:

DNS (all with same servers)

```
rickenba.ch.            IN  A   xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
www.rickenba.ch.        IN  A   xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
ateachersblog.com.      IN  A   xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
www.ateachersblog.com   IN  A   xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Network admin

```
Site 1 URL: http://rickenbach.ch/blog/
Site 2 URL: http://ateachersblog.com/ (used to be http://rickenbach.ch/blog/en)
```

.htaccess in root

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

 # uploaded files
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

 # add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```